# Spring autowired can not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I currently developing an application using Spring Data Neo4j. This is the first time I use Spring framework.

However, the autowired annotation is not working, I always get null. Here is the codes:

```
    public class CreateDiaryTransaction extends Transaction {
    @Autowired
    DirayRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Object perform(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Diary diary = (Diary) DiaryFactory.getInstance().create(parameters);
        repository.save(diary);
        return diary.toJsonRepre();
    }
}
```

Then I test it in a unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "/applicationContext.xml" })
public class CreateDiaryTransactionTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Transaction transaction = new CreateDiaryTransaction();
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("title", "Test");
        parameters.put("weather", "sun");
        parameters.put("mood", "happy");
        parameters.put("html", "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\">link</a>");
        parameters.put("images", new ArrayList<Image>());
        try {
            transaction.execute(parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Exception occur");
        }
    }
}
```

When I runs this, I got null object exception. However, when I place the repository directly in the unit test, it works fine. Here is another test that works:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "/applicationContext.xml" })
public class DiaryRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    DirayRepository repository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testSaveDiary() {
        Diary diary = (Diary) DiaryFactory.getInstance().create(
                new HashMap<String, Object>());
        repository.save(diary);

        Diary retrivedDiary = repository.findOne(diary.getGraphId());
        assertEquals(diary, retrivedDiary);
    }

}
```

And here is my application context:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/data/pamela"
    base-package="com.bond.pamela.domain" />
<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.bond.pamela.persistence" />
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" />

<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean
                class="com.bond.pamela.domain.valueObject.converter.ImageToJsonConverter" />
            <bean
                class="com.bond.pamela.domain.valueObject.converter.JsonToImageConverter" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I guess I somehow put the repository outside the spring context, but how can I get it wirte? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need following in your application context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="packagename.package" />
```

Here package name is package in which you have all your classes with annotations.

Have a look at this post for more :

[Spring MVC: Difference between context:annotation-config vs context:component-scan](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/07/19/spring-mvc-difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan/)

Comment: You also need to add "@Repository" or "@Component" at top of the class  .... Thanks to @sarvesh

Comment: it works! thx man. I at the @Component annotation to transactions I need and use <context: component-scan> to register them so that Spring treat it as Spring bean. However, I have one more question. I also have another package contains component, so how can I register them as well? Add another <context: component-scan>.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.service, x.y.z.controller" /> 

OR

  <context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z />  will take all packages under x.y.z .....I would recommend second approach...

Comment: you can mark this as correct answer if it is solved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have written `@Repository` or `@Component` annotation on the implementation of `DirayRepository` and you have written component-scan in
`applicationContext.xml`

sample code for  `DirayRepository`

```
@Repository
  public class DirayRepositoryImpl implements DirayRepository {
   void save() { ...}

  }
```